# How do I create support set, positive and negative pairs for siamese network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, siamese-network

I have a siamese that takes a pair of inputs. I want to create positive, negative and support sets to train the network that I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433413/how-to-create-image-pairs-for-siamese-network-using-keras-imagedatagenerator). Positive pair: images from same view (or maybe different view ) and the same category. Negative pairs: Different categories and different views. I have the following folder structure.

```
+---aluminium_foil
|   +---view1
|   |       15a-scale_2_im_1_col.png
|   |       15a-scale_3_im_1_col.png
|   |       15a-scale_4_im_1_col.png
|   |       
|   +---view2
|   |       15a-scale_2_im_2_col.png
|   |       15a-scale_3_im_2_col.png
|   |       
|   \---view3
|           15a-scale_2_im_3_col.png
|           15a-scale_3_im_3_col.png
|           15a-scale_4_im_3_col.png
|           15a-scale_5_im_3_col.png
|           15a-scale_6_im_3_col.png
|           
+---brown_bread
|   +---view1
|   |       48a-scale_2_im_1_col.png
|   |       48a-scale_3_im_1_col.png
|   |       48a-scale_4_im_1_col.png
|   |       48a-scale_5_im_1_col.png
|   |       
|   +---view2
|   |       48a-scale_2_im_3_col.png
|   |       48a-scale_3_im_3_col.png
|   |       48a-scale_5_im_3_col.png
|   |       48a-scale_6_im_3_col.png
|   |       48a-scale_7_im_3_col.png
|   |       
|   \---view3
|           48a-scale_2_im_5_col.png
|           48a-scale_2_im_6_col.png
|           48a-scale_3_im_5_col.png
|           48a-scale_3_im_6_col.png
|           
+---corduroy
|   +---view1
|   |       42a-scale_2_im_1_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_2_im_2_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_3_im_1_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_3_im_2_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_4_im_1_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_4_im_2_col.png
|   |       
|   +---view2
|   |       42a-scale_4_im_4_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_4_im_5_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_4_im_6_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_4_im_7_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_5_im_4_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_5_im_5_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_5_im_6_col.png
|   |       42a-scale_5_im_7_col.png
|   |       
|   \---view3
|           42a-scale_2_im_10_col.png
|           42a-scale_2_im_11_col.png
|           42a-scale_2_im_12_col.png
|           42a-scale_3_im_10_col.png
|           42a-scale_3_im_11_col.png
|           42a-scale_3_im_12_col.png
|           
+---cork
|   +---view1
|   |       16a-scale_2_im_1_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_2_im_2_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_2_im_3_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_2_im_4_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_2_im_5_col.png
|   |       
|   +---view2
|   |       16a-scale_3_im_3_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_3_im_4_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_3_im_5_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_3_im_6_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_4_im_3_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_4_im_4_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_4_im_5_col.png
|   |       16a-scale_4_im_6_col.png
|   |       
|   \---view3
|           16a-scale_8_im_10_col.png
|           16a-scale_8_im_11_col.png
|           
\---cotton
    +---view1
    |       46a-scale_3_im_1_col.png
    |       46a-scale_3_im_2_col.png
    |       
    +---view2
    |       46a-scale_2_im_10_col.png
    |       46a-scale_2_im_11_col.png
    |       46a-scale_2_im_12_col.png
    |       46a-scale_3_im_10_col.png
    |       46a-scale_3_im_11_col.png
    |       46a-scale_3_im_12_col.png
    |       
    \---view3
            46a-scale_5_im_10_col.png
            46a-scale_5_im_11_col.png
            46a-scale_5_im_12_col.png
.
.
.
```

I wrote the code to make pairs for the following folder structure.

```
+---aluminium_foil
|       v3_s1_patch_1.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_10.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_11.JPG
|       
+---brown_bread
|       v3_s1_patch_11.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_12.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_13.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_14.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_15.JPG
|       
+---corduroy
|       v3_s1_patch_1.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_10.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_11.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_12.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_13.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_17.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_18.JPG
|       
+---cork
|       v3_s1_patch_10.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_11.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_12.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_13.JPG
|       
+---cotton
|       v3_s1_patch_1.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_10.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_11.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_12.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_13.JPG

+---lettuce_leaf
|       v3_s1_patch_1.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_10.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_11.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_12.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_16.JPG
|       v3_s1_patch_17.JPG
```

Here is my code to make positive and negative pairs for folder structure like above.

```
def load_data_set(data_path, image_size = (224,224)):
    """
    Load images in numpy array. Images are loaded in RGB format.
    Input: Main data directory and image size in 2D.
    Output: X and Y as numpy array.
    """
    directory_list = os.listdir(path=data_path)
    directory_list.sort()
    x_data = list()
    y_data = list()

    for directory in directory_list:
        class_path = os.path.join(data_path, directory)
        image_names = os.listdir(path=class_path)
        image_names.sort()
        for image_name in image_names:
            image_array = cv2.imread(
                os.path.join(class_path, image_name), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR
            )
            image_array = cv2.cvtColor(image_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image_array = cv2.resize(image_array, image_size)
            x_data.append(image_array)
            y_data.append(directory)

    x_data = np.array(x_data)
    y_data = np.array(y_data)

    return x_data, y_data

def positive_pair(x_value, y_value, augmentation= False):
    """
    Create a random positive duplet from the data.
    If augmentation is True, then image augmentation is applied
    for both images of negative duplet.
    """
    random_index = random.randint(0, x_value.shape[0] - 1)

    if augmentation is True:
        x_anchor = image_augmentation(x_value[random_index])
    else:
        x_anchor = x_value[random_index]

    y_anchor = y_value[random_index]
    pos_index = np.squeeze(np.where(y_value == y_anchor))

    if augmentation is True:
        x_positive = image_augmentation(
            x_value[pos_index[random.randint(0, len(pos_index) - 1)]]
        )
    else:
        x_positive = x_value[pos_index[random.randint(0, len(pos_index) - 1)]]

    return [x_anchor, x_positive], 1.0


def negative_pair(x_value, y_value, augmentation = False):
    """
    Create a random negative duplet from the data.
    If augmentation is True, then image augmentation is applied
    for both images of negative duplet.
    """
    random_index = random.randint(0, x_value.shape[0] - 1)

    if augmentation is True:
        x_anchor = image_augmentation(x_value[random_index])
    else:
        x_anchor = x_value[random_index]

    y_anchor = y_value[random_index]
    neg_index = np.squeeze(np.where(y_value != y_anchor))

    if augmentation is True:
        x_negative = image_augmentation(
            x_value[neg_index[random.randint(0, len(neg_index) - 1)]]
        )
    else:
        x_negative = x_value[neg_index[random.randint(0, len(neg_index) - 1)]]

    return [x_anchor, x_negative], 0.0
```

I also want to create support set like [image: this]. How do I adopt my existing code to create positive and negative pairs as well as support sets for the folder structure that is mentioned above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same question, I figured out how to create positive and negative pairs for such a folder structure.

***To read the images from directory***

```
def get_dataset(path):
    
    x_data = list()
    y_data = list()
    v_data = list()

    image_size = (224,224)

    for filename in glob.iglob(path + '**/*.JPG', recursive=True):
        view_folder = str(filename.split('/')[-3])
        class_folder = str(filename.split('/')[-2])

        image_array = cv2.imread(filename,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        image_array = cv2.cvtColor(image_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image_array = cv2.resize(image_array, image_size)

        x_data.append(image_array)
        y_data.append(class_folder)
        v_data.append(view_folder)
    
    x_data = np.array(x_data)
    y_data = np.array(y_data)
    v_data = np.array(v_data)
    
    return x_data/255.0, y_data, v_data
```

***To create positive and negative pairs from the data***

```
def positive_duplet(x_value, y_value, v_value):
    """
    Create a random positive duplet from data.
    for the both images of negative duplet.
    """
    random_index = random.randint(0, x_value.shape[0] - 1)

    x_anchor = x_value[random_index]
    v_anchor = v_value[random_index]

    y_anchor = y_value[random_index]
    pos_index = np.squeeze(np.where( (y_value == y_anchor) & (v_value == v_anchor ) ) )
    
    
    x_positive = x_value[pos_index[random.randint(0, len(pos_index) - 1)]]

    return [x_anchor, x_positive], 1.0


def negative_duplet(x_value, y_value, v_value):
    """
    Create a random negative duplet from data.
    for the both images of negative duplet.
    """
    random_index = random.randint(0, x_value.shape[0] - 1)

    x_anchor = x_value[random_index]
    v_anchor = v_value[random_index]

    y_anchor = y_value[random_index]
    neg_index = np.squeeze(np.where( (y_value != y_anchor) & (v_value != v_anchor) ) )
    #print(neg_index)

    x_negative = x_value[neg_index[random.randint(0, len(neg_index) - 1)]]

    return [x_anchor, x_negative], 0.0
```