# KNN classifier gives different results when using predict and kneighbors from sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, knn, nearest-neighbor

I want to classify the extracted features from a CNN with k-nearest neighbors classifier from sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier. But when I used predict() function on test data it gives a class different than the majority votes that can be found by kneighbors(). I am using the following Resnet50 pretrained model to extract the features which is a branch of a siamese network. Details of the siamese network can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433413/how-to-create-image-pairs-for-siamese-network-using-keras-imagedatagenerator).

```
def embedding_model():
    
    baseModel = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,input_tensor=Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)))
    for layer in baseModel.layers[:165]:
        layer.trainable = False
    
    headModel = baseModel.output
    headModel = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(headModel)
    model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel, name = 'embedding_model')

    return model

#get embedding model weights from saved weights
embeddings_weights = siamese_test.get_layer('embedding_model').get_weights()
embeddings_branch = siamese_test.get_layer('embedding_model')

input_shape = (224,224,3)

input = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = embeddings_branch(input)

model = Model(input, x)
model.set_weights(embeddings_weights )
out_shape = model.layers[-1].output_shape
```

Model summary can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WLtJ.png). I used the following function to extract the features using the model.

```
def create_features(dataset, pre_model,out_shape,batchSize=16):
    features = pre_model.predict(dataset, batchSize)
    features_flatten = features.reshape((features.shape[0], out_shape[1] ))
    return features, features_flatten
train_features, train_features_flatten = create_features(x_train,model,out_shape, batchSize)
test_features, test_features_flatten = create_features(x_test,model,out_shape, batchSize)
```

Then I used KNN classifier to predict on test features

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

KNN_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
KNN_classifier.fit(train_features_flatten, y_train)

y_pred = KNN_classifier.predict(test_features_flatten)
```

I used keighbors() function to find the nearest neighbors distance and their corresponding index. But it gives me different results than the predicted one.

```
neighbors_dist, neighbors_index = KNN_classifier.kneighbors(test_features_flatten)

#replace the index with actual class 
data2 = np.zeros(neighbors_index.shape, dtype=object)
for i in range(neighbors_index.shape[0]):
  for j in range(neighbors_index.shape[1]):
    data2[i,j] = str(y_test[neighbors_index[i][j]])

#get the majority class 
from collections import Counter
majority_class = np.array([Counter(sorted(row, reverse=True)).most_common(1)[0][0] for row in data2])
```

As you can see the predicted class is not same as the majority class for first 10 samples

```
for i, pred in enumerate(y_pred):
  print(i,pred)

for i, c in enumerate(majority_class):
  print(i,c)
```

**Predicted output for first 10 samples:**
0 corduroy
1 wool
2 wool
3 brown_bread
4 wood
5 corduroy
6 corduroy
7 corduroy
8 wool
9 wood
10 corduroy

**Majority class for first 10 samples:**
0 corduroy
1 cork
2 cork
3 lettuce_leaf
4 linen
5 corduroy
6 wool
7 corduroy
8 brown_bread
9 linen
10 wool

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```py
    data2[i,j] = str(y_test[neighbors_index[i][j]])
```

The `kneighbors` method (and also `predict`) finds the nearest *training* points to the inputs,  so you should reference `y_train` here.

Comment: Hi Ben Reiniger thank you for the answer . That solves the problem. I am accepting your answer.